# Changes index of elements in Array in a C# console app, but when runs it return index remain same

Tags: c#, console-application

I've just changed the indexes of elements in an array. When I run the code and search a specific element using Array.BinarySearch(); It still returns the same indexes as before I changed them.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int indexno;
        string schooltype;
        Array schools= Array.CreateInstance(typeof(string), 3);
        schools.SetValue("Middle School", 0);
        schools.SetValue("High School", 1);
        schools.SetValue("Univercity", 2);
        Array.Sort(schools);
        Console.Write("What type of school are you looking for: ");
        schooltype = Console.ReadLine();
        indexno = Array.BinarySearch(schools, schooltype.ToString());
        if (indexno<0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("School type not exist. ");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Index of the school type is " + indexno);
        }
```

Comment: If you ever find yourself declaring `Array` in C#, things have gone horribly wrong.

Comment: Also, `schooltype` is **already** a string. Calling `ToString()` for it makes no sense. But if you really want help with this, we also need to see exactly what you typed in for the prompt, and what it showed you for the output.

Comment: For me your code works

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen a variable declared as `Array` in real production code. We might use the `Array` static methods, but declaring a variable that way just doesn't happen.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] schools = {"Middle School", "High School", "University"};
    Array.Sort(schools); //uses default comparer... be careful of mixed case values

    //verify new order
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n", schools));

    Console.Write("What type of school are you looking for: ");
    var schooltype = Console.ReadLine();

    var result = "School type not exist. ";
    var index = Array.BinarySearch(schools, schooltype);
    if (index >= 0)
    { 
        result = $"Index of the school type is {index}";
    }
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

This code returned correct indexes for all three possible school types:

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/fjpOOb